# Как включить подсказки для JavaScript в Eclipse?

Tags: javascript, eclipse

Для Java, HTML, CSS подсказки работают, а для JavaScript нет.

Comment: http://www.eclipse.org/pdt/help/html/using_javascript_content_assist.htm

Comment: Не помогло. Всё равно подсказок нет

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20765144/any-working-javascript-auto-completion-or-content-assist-for-eclipse